# O que significa a expressão "Porto Santo Alerta, bonança certa!"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões, português-europeu

> Porto Santo Alerta, bonança certa!!

O que significa esta expressão? Como surgiu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que a expressão é de origem madeirense, uma vez que "Porto Santo" se refere à segunda ilha do arquipélago da Madeira.

[Segundo a história da região,](https://www.visitportugal.com/pt-pt/content/ilha-de-porto-santo) a ilha foi descoberta em 1418 pelos navegadores João Gonçalves Zarco e Tristão Vaz Teixeira, que, tendo sido desviados por ventos fortes da sua rota de exploração da costa ocidental de África, encontraram na ilha um "porto seguro". Este acontecimento foi o que deu origem ao nome da ilha ("Porto Santo").

Assim, avistar Porto Santo representa um bom presságio para os navegadores. Daí a origem da expressão ["Porto Santo alerta, bonança certa"](https://web.archive.org/web/20200127014757/http://aprenderamadeira.net/proverbios-e-outros-ditos-populares) (*=* bom tempo, mar calmo, boa viagem marítima).